# Hierarchical states using non hierarchical views in AgularJS ui-router

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-ui-router, nested-views

I have to build a page with three columns:

```
<div>
   <div>Library Column</div>
   <div>Book Column</div>
   <div>Page Column</div>
</div>
```

I have 3 hierarchical ui states:

```
.state("library", {
    url: "/library",
    templateUrl: "../app/views/library.html", // <div>Library Column</div>
    controller: "libraryCtrl"
})
    .state("library.book", {
        url: "/:bookid",
        templateUrl: "../app/views/book.html", // <div>Book Column</div>
        controller: 'bookCtrl'
    })
        .state("library.detail.publish", {
            url: "/:pagenr",
            templateUrl: "../app/views/page.html", // <div>Page Column1</div>
            controller: 'pageCtrl'
        })
```

I can't figure out where and how put the ui-view attributes in the different view .html files to achieve a non hierarchical view layout based on hierarchical states.

index.html:

```
<div ui-view></div>
```

library.html:

```
<div>Library Column</div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

book.html:

```
<div>Book Column</div>
<div ui-view></div>
```

page.html:

```
<div>Page Column</div>
```

obviously ends up with a hierarchical view layout, which is not acceptable for my case (for example state #/library/1/20):

```
<div ui-view>
   <div>Library Column</div>
   <div ui-view>
        <div>Book Column: Book 1</div>
        <div ui-view>
            <div>Page Column: Page 20</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to maintain the state hierarchy but force the child views to be siblings of their parents?